# How to stop rotation on `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:`

Tags: iphone, ipad, rotation

I need a way to force the orientation back to portrait on rotate.

The problem is that I have a Tab bar controller, but only want one of the tabs to autorotate.

So I have allowed rotation on all tabs and now I need a way to intercept a rotation on a tab where I don't want to allow rotation.

I'm guessing I can do this on `- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration`?

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to force rotation. In case of a `UITabBarController` you are out of luck. It is an all or nothing situation wrt interface rotation. If one of your tabs cannot rotate then the whole `UITabBarController` stays in portrait mode fixed.

Comment: thanks. :) I've just had to make all my views rotate-able. :p

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would even work if implemented in all your viewControllers:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return (return ([[self.tabBarController.selectedViewController class] isSubclassOfClass:[TurnableViewController class]]) || UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation);
}
```

This will, however, not turn back your view if you switch back to a non-turnable, until you tilt your device...